# Colorbox display loading GIF between iframes

Tags: colorbox

I'm using colorbox to load an external page in an iframe. As the page is loading you can see the loading GIF. All is good so far :)

Once the page is loaded, there is a form with a submit button. When I click the button, it loads a second page in to the same iframe. This all works fine, except it doesn't show the loading GIF while the second external page is loading.

Is there a way I can get this to show when I click the submit button, then once the page has loaded hide it again?

Comment: Where is this loading gif? In the iframe or out of it? If in, is it part of the first iframe page?

Comment: it's inside the iframe, part of colorbox not the first iframe page

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference in the behavior is this: the first load of the iframe is accomplished by ColorBox, which includes code to display the spinner. The second event is triggered by (I assume) your submit button so the ColorBox plugin isn't called.

This isn't strictly a ColorBox question, BTW, but I suggest you study the plug-in's code to see if you can reuse the technique that displays the spinner. Just a thought.

In any case, you'll likely need some javascript to handle the spinner display and event timings.